# Contact form 7 special mail tags not working

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form which is inside a custom post type in a theme template. I want to get current post title when forms sends email to admin. The email works perfectly, but I am not getting post title.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'career_jobs', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
                    
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                    ?>
                    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $job_number = 0; ?>
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                    $job_number++;
                    ?>

<button type="submit" id="testing" class="btn btn-primary submit-cv-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#jobform" data-whatever="@mdo">Submit CV</button>

<div class="modal fade p-0" id="jobform" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
                            <div class="container pop-up-wrap-body p-1">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h1 class="modal-title lets-modal-header" id="exampleModalLabel">Submit <span class="sub-heading-lets">CV</span></h1>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/includes/images/footer/close.png" class="img-fluid"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <h5 class="lets-modal-sub-header">Start work with us</h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container pop-up-wrap p-0 p-lg-4">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <?php $form = get_field("add_form_shortcode"); 
                                                echo do_shortcode("'". $form. "'");
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="container-fluid pop-up-footer">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 pop-up-footer-text">
                                                <p>1-888-251-1622<br> info@techmatix.nl</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12 pop-up-footer-text">
                                                <p>Transistorstraat 31, 1322 CK<br> Almere, Netherlands</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

I am using [_post_title] special mail tag in mail tab on wordpress.

Comment: Can you share the shortcode?

Comment: do you have same tag ([_post_title] ) in email template in "message body" field?

Comment: @Beneris
Here is the shortcode [contact-form-7 id="53" title="Job Form"]

Comment: @Beneris Yes, I have used [_post_title] in the message body field.